# Hide elements containing links to a certain domain in uBlock Origin

Tags: ublock-origin

Using uBlock Origin, can I hide (eg. `display: none`) all `<article>` elements anywhere on `example.org` that contains links to anywhere on `example.com`?

`example.org/somepath/somepage.html:`

```
...
<article>
...
<a href="http://www.example.com/foo/bar/"><img src="..."/></a>
...
<p><a href="http://www.example.com/abc/def/">Hello World</a></p>
...
</article>
....
```

Comment: Nowadays we might use something using :has() or :upward() operators which are easier than xpath. Could look like this: `example.org##a[href*="example.com"]:upward(.article)`

Answer (score 5):

uBlock origin supports [XPath filters](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Procedural-cosmetic-filters#subjectxpatharg). XPath is able to select elements based on child elements, in contrast to CSS selectors:

```
##:xpath(//article[.//a[contains(@href,"://www.example.com")]])
```

This filters all articles that contain a link to www.example.com, either http or https.

Comment: Thanks a lot! XPath is a bit intimidating, but at least there's a possibility! Is there a official, user-friendly tutorial/manual that takes you through the different ways uBlock Origin can be used in common use cases? Using it has something of a threshold. (In particular, I'm wondering how to block tag names that are random-generated.)